# How to exit batch processing at beginning of a batch file when a file already exists?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I have a batch file and my goal is to use it only once. On further executions this batch file should do nothing. To solve this task, I decided to use `If Exist` to check for a file created at the end of the batch script.
So at the very beginning I have this (I go to the correct directory):

```
If Exist "file.txt" (
goto exit
)
```

I set an `exit` marker at the end of the file.

Alternate methods will be appreciated but I'd prefer the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goto [manual](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) says :

> Direct a batch program to jump to a labelled line.
>
> Syntax
>         GOTO label

I guess the label(I would not use the term **marker**) name should not be `exit` as a windows command exists with the same name. Change the label to

```
:exitprocess
```

and do

```
if exist "file.txt" goto exitprocess
```

However, if you wish to use `exit` as a label the workaround is to use

```
if exist "file.txt" goto :exit
```

Mind the **colon**, this is tell goto to find the label named `exit`

**Courtesy** : @somethingdark for the workaround.

Comment: He should be able to say `goto :exit`, though. But I agree; in general, you should try to avoid labels having the same name as commands.

Comment: I will try it ASAP (tomorrow) if it works I'll give you the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, also realized I misspelled "exit" and instead put "exist" in my If exist block.

Comment: @EliR : Thanks for accepting the answer. It was an easy fix though. I bet you would easily find if you skim a second time through it.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft explains for [GOTO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755012.aspx) the possibility to use

```
goto :EOF
```

to exit processing of a batch file or a batch subroutine whereby the label **EOF** (End Of File) is predefined and must not be explicitly defined in batch file.

Another method to exit processing of a batch file or a batch subroutine is using the command [EXIT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770929.aspx) with parameter `/B`, i.e.

```
exit /B
```

This exits just the batch processing and not entire command process which makes a difference on using **EXIT** for exiting a batch subroutine or when batch file is called from another batch file.

So it can be used for this task either

```
if exist "file.txt" goto :EOF
```

or

```
if exist "file.txt" exit /B
```

Both lines result on exiting current batch processing and return to calling process which is the command process itself when the batch file was called directly resulting in exiting the command process, too.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, also realized I misspelled "exit" and instead put "exist" in my If exist block. I gave the other guy best answer since he answered first however your answer was just as good.